# Is it a good solution to use temp table where there can be dependency involved among tables?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view, mysql-workbench, temp-tables

I need to insert values to one final summary table, from a lot of several different summary tables.

I first need to perform various summations on some of these small summary tables, on some I need to calculate averages, on some sum of averages. To achieve this, I created views (around 21 views) and then one view (that is union of select statements for joining 21 views). Then I created stored procedure to call this view and insert values to one final summary table. I able to achieve what I wanted but is this a clean solution ? Can I create temp tables with/without using SP? Will dependency be impacted by having temp tables? I have dependency of views on each other , specially the final view which is union of all other views to calculate final summary of all tables.

Comment: To my mind, views serve no useful purpose in MySQL.

Comment: @Strawberry what is the better solution other than views?

Comment: Queries will suffice.

Comment: I was able to work around this. Simply created SP, that creates temp tables. these temp tables contains select statements to calculate summation, average depending on what I wanted from each temp table. Then in same SP,  I inserted data from these temp tables to summary table using insert query and doing UNION of all temp tables.

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer, and then 'accept' that answer when the system allows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this. Simply created SP, that creates temp tables. these temp tables contains select statements to calculate summation, average depending on what I wanted from each temp table. Then in same SP, I inserted data from these temp tables to summary table using insert query and doing UNION of all temp tables